# R function for simple lookup replacement of excel

Tags: r, merge, vlookup, lookup, plyr

I want to extract the values form file 2 to file matching the values in indicated columns. It is a simple lookup function in Excel. 
but many solutions given are based on matching column names which I don't want change in my data set.

[2 files having a matching column and file2 column to be inserted in file1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgPoo.jpg)

Comment: merge(file1, unique(file2)[, c("Symbol", "GeneID")], by="UniprotBlastGeneSymbol")                         is outputting  Error in `[.default`(unique(file2$Symbol), , c("Symbol", "GeneID")) : 
  incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: file2%>%
+     select(Symbol, GeneID) %>%
+     distinct() %>%
+     left_join(file1, by = file1$UniprotBlastGeneSymbol)
Error: `by` can't contain join column `DIR23`, `At5g34650`, `At1g53800`, `At2g30060`, `PER59`, ... which is missing from LHS
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

Answer (score 0):

As  your column names are different in the two data.frames you need to tell `merge` which columns correspond to each other:

```
merge(file1, unique(file2[, c("Symbol", "GeneID"))], by.x="UniprotBlastGeneSymbol", by.y="Symbol")
```

Your result column will be called `GeneID`, not `Column4`, of course. If `file2` contains gene Ids that are not found in `file1` then you may also want `all.y=FALSE`.